# How to put this line on latex

Tags: formatting, two-column

I was doing a double side article and I need to put a line structure, which is circled in red in the following figure. What command do I use to reproduce in latex that thing? I don't know how is it called, I couldn't find it even with detexity, so this question is most likely a duplicate.

[image: Example.]

Comment: Realy, this may be a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324923/partial-lines-above-and-below-an-equation-in-a-multicols-environment (asked by me ;-)).

Answer (score 9):

**Revtex-4.1**

If you're using Revtex 4.1, then the `widetext` environment is already defined.

[image: revtex]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{widetext}
         \[
        1+1 = 2 \tag{27}
        \]
    \end{widetext}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

**Article etc.**

If you're using any other document class other than Revtex, you're going to need the `widetext.sty` obtained [here](https://gist.github.com/Liam0205/014661fe1fb0c337bfa0dd3242430015).

[image: article]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum,widetext}
% Obtain widetext.sty from https://gist.github.com/Liam0205/014661fe1fb0c337bfa0dd3242430015

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{widetext}
         \[
        1+1 = 2 \tag{27}
        \]
    \end{widetext}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---